# How to show a table of displayed ggplot() data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to be able to show a table of any ggplot data.  This is relatively easy where no calculations are done, but seems much more difficult when a stat is calculated.

I'm wondering if there is any catch-all way to do this for any type of table, or at the very least for bar-type tables (`geom_bar()`, `geom_col()`, `geom_histogram()`).

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
#geom_col
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs = as.factor(vs)) %>% 
  count(vs, carb) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = carb, y = n, fill = vs)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

This is relatively easy when no stat is calculated

```r
last_plot()$data
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   vs     carb     n
#>   <fct> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 0         2     5
#> 2 0         3     3
#> 3 0         4     8
#> 4 0         6     1
#> 5 0         8     1
#> 6 1         1     7
#> 7 1         2     5
#> 8 1         4     2
```

But not so easy when we have a calculated stat:

```r
#geom_histogram
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs = as.factor(vs)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, fill = vs)) + geom_histogram()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
last_plot()$data #This isn't what we want, since there was a calculated stat.
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> 11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> 12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> 13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> 14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> 15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> 16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> 17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> 18 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> 19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> 20 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> 21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> 22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> 23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> 24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> 25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> 26 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> 27 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> 28 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> 29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> 30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> 31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> 32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Here we have what we're after, but we don't know what "group" is what so that needs to be reconnected.

```r
gb <- ggplot_build(last_plot())$data[[1]]
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.


gb %>% select(y, count, x, group)
#>    y count         x group
#> 1  1     1  48.79310     2
#> 2  1     0  48.79310     1
#> 3  1     1  58.55172     2
#> 4  1     0  58.55172     1
#> 5  3     3  68.31034     2
#> 6  3     0  68.31034     1
#> 7  0     0  78.06897     2
#> 8  0     0  78.06897     1
#> 9  0     0  87.82759     2
#> 10 1     1  87.82759     1
#> 11 3     3  97.58621     2
#> 12 3     0  97.58621     1
#> 13 3     3 107.34483     2
#> 14 5     2 107.34483     1
#> 15 1     1 117.10345     2
#> 16 1     0 117.10345     1
#> 17 2     2 126.86207     2
#> 18 2     0 126.86207     1
#> 19 0     0 136.62069     2
#> 20 0     0 136.62069     1
#> 21 0     0 146.37931     2
#> 22 2     2 146.37931     1
#> 23 0     0 156.13793     2
#> 24 0     0 156.13793     1
#> 25 0     0 165.89655     2
#> 26 0     0 165.89655     1
#> 27 0     0 175.65517     2
#> 28 6     6 175.65517     1
#> 29 0     0 185.41379     2
#> 30 0     0 185.41379     1
#> 31 0     0 195.17241     2
#> 32 0     0 195.17241     1
#> 33 0     0 204.93103     2
#> 34 1     1 204.93103     1
#> 35 0     0 214.68966     2
#> 36 1     1 214.68966     1
#> 37 0     0 224.44828     2
#> 38 0     0 224.44828     1
#> 39 0     0 234.20690     2
#> 40 1     1 234.20690     1
#> 41 0     0 243.96552     2
#> 42 2     2 243.96552     1
#> 43 0     0 253.72414     2
#> 44 0     0 253.72414     1
#> 45 0     0 263.48276     2
#> 46 1     1 263.48276     1
#> 47 0     0 273.24138     2
#> 48 0     0 273.24138     1
#> 49 0     0 283.00000     2
#> 50 0     0 283.00000     1
#> 51 0     0 292.75862     2
#> 52 0     0 292.75862     1
#> 53 0     0 302.51724     2
#> 54 0     0 302.51724     1
#> 55 0     0 312.27586     2
#> 56 0     0 312.27586     1
#> 57 0     0 322.03448     2
#> 58 0     0 322.03448     1
#> 59 0     0 331.79310     2
#> 60 1     1 331.79310     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

And it will likely be further complicated when we have facets, colors, etc.

EDIT UPDATE:

Sorry this wasn't clear. `vs` was a terrible choice for the fill because it happens to be numeric.  Here's a slightly improved version, showing that when the fill value is character, you still get a numeric value for group.

```r
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs = case_when(vs == 0 ~ "random",
                        vs == 1 ~ "character label")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, fill = vs)) + geom_histogram()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
last_plot()$data #This isn't what we want, since there was a calculated stat.
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec              vs am gear carb
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46          random  1    4    4
#> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02          random  1    4    4
#> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61 character label  1    4    1
#> 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44 character label  0    3    1
#> 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02          random  0    3    2
#> 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22 character label  0    3    1
#> 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84          random  0    3    4
#> 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00 character label  0    4    2
#> 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90 character label  0    4    2
#> 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30 character label  0    4    4
#> 11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90 character label  0    4    4
#> 12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40          random  0    3    3
#> 13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60          random  0    3    3
#> 14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00          random  0    3    3
#> 15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98          random  0    3    4
#> 16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82          random  0    3    4
#> 17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42          random  0    3    4
#> 18 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47 character label  1    4    1
#> 19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52 character label  1    4    2
#> 20 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90 character label  1    4    1
#> 21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01 character label  0    3    1
#> 22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87          random  0    3    2
#> 23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30          random  0    3    2
#> 24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41          random  0    3    4
#> 25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05          random  0    3    2
#> 26 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90 character label  1    4    1
#> 27 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70          random  1    5    2
#> 28 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90 character label  1    5    2
#> 29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50          random  1    5    4
#> 30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50          random  1    5    6
#> 31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60          random  1    5    8
#> 32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60 character label  1    4    2

gb <- ggplot_build(last_plot())$data[[1]]
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.

#Here we have what we're after, but we don't know what "group" is what so that needs to be reconnected.
gb %>% select(y, count, x, group)
#>    y count         x group
#> 1  0     0  48.79310     2
#> 2  1     1  48.79310     1
#> 3  0     0  58.55172     2
#> 4  1     1  58.55172     1
#> 5  0     0  68.31034     2
#> 6  3     3  68.31034     1
#> 7  0     0  78.06897     2
#> 8  0     0  78.06897     1
#> 9  1     1  87.82759     2
#> 10 1     0  87.82759     1
#> 11 0     0  97.58621     2
#> 12 3     3  97.58621     1
#> 13 2     2 107.34483     2
#> 14 5     3 107.34483     1
#> 15 0     0 117.10345     2
#> 16 1     1 117.10345     1
#> 17 0     0 126.86207     2
#> 18 2     2 126.86207     1
#> 19 0     0 136.62069     2
#> 20 0     0 136.62069     1
#> 21 2     2 146.37931     2
#> 22 2     0 146.37931     1
#> 23 0     0 156.13793     2
#> 24 0     0 156.13793     1
#> 25 0     0 165.89655     2
#> 26 0     0 165.89655     1
#> 27 6     6 175.65517     2
#> 28 6     0 175.65517     1
#> 29 0     0 185.41379     2
#> 30 0     0 185.41379     1
#> 31 0     0 195.17241     2
#> 32 0     0 195.17241     1
#> 33 1     1 204.93103     2
#> 34 1     0 204.93103     1
#> 35 1     1 214.68966     2
#> 36 1     0 214.68966     1
#> 37 0     0 224.44828     2
#> 38 0     0 224.44828     1
#> 39 1     1 234.20690     2
#> 40 1     0 234.20690     1
#> 41 2     2 243.96552     2
#> 42 2     0 243.96552     1
#> 43 0     0 253.72414     2
#> 44 0     0 253.72414     1
#> 45 1     1 263.48276     2
#> 46 1     0 263.48276     1
#> 47 0     0 273.24138     2
#> 48 0     0 273.24138     1
#> 49 0     0 283.00000     2
#> 50 0     0 283.00000     1
#> 51 0     0 292.75862     2
#> 52 0     0 292.75862     1
#> 53 0     0 302.51724     2
#> 54 0     0 302.51724     1
#> 55 0     0 312.27586     2
#> 56 0     0 312.27586     1
#> 57 0     0 322.03448     2
#> 58 0     0 322.03448     1
#> 59 1     1 331.79310     2
#> 60 1     0 331.79310     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

=======================

EDIT 2
As requested, here's a cleaner working example of what I"m after:

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse

diamonds %>% 
  filter(color == "E" | color == "J") %>% 
  filter(cut == "Good" | cut == "Premium") %>% 
  filter(price < 400) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = price, fill = cut)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 10, position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~color)
```

[image]

```r
p <- last_plot() #this is important, because I want to insert this function after an existing plot
p$data #This is filtered, but it's not what we want because it isn't binned and so doesn't match the ggplot.
#> # A tibble: 41 x 10
#>    carat cut     color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>    <dbl> <ord>   <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.21 Premium E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#>  2  0.23 Good    E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#>  3  0.31 Good    J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#>  4  0.3  Good    J     SI1      64      55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73
#>  5  0.2  Premium E     SI2      60.2    62   345  3.79  3.75  2.27
#>  6  0.32 Premium E     I1       60.9    58   345  4.38  4.42  2.68
#>  7  0.3  Good    J     SI1      63.4    54   351  4.23  4.29  2.7 
#>  8  0.3  Good    J     SI1      63.8    56   351  4.23  4.26  2.71
#>  9  0.23 Good    E     VS2      61.8    63   357  3.88  3.89  2.4 
#> 10  0.25 Good    E     VS1      63.3    60   361  3.99  4.04  2.54
#> # … with 31 more rows

pgb_data <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]


#This has the data, but doesn't tell us the label of the facet, or the label of the fill:
pgb_data %>% 
  select(x, y, count, group, PANEL)
#>           x y count group PANEL
#> 1  326.7778 1     1     2     1
#> 2  323.0000 1     1     1     1
#> 3  334.3333 0     0     2     1
#> 4  330.5556 0     0     1     1
#> 5  341.8889 0     0     2     1
#> 6  338.1111 0     0     1     1
#> 7  349.4444 2     2     2     1
#> 8  345.6667 0     0     1     1
#> 9  357.0000 0     0     2     1
#> 10 353.2222 1     1     1     1
#> 11 364.5556 0     0     2     1
#> 12 360.7778 1     1     1     1
#> 13 372.1111 4     4     2     1
#> 14 368.3333 2     2     1     1
#> 15 379.6667 0     0     2     1
#> 16 375.8889 2     2     1     1
#> 17 387.2222 2     2     2     1
#> 18 383.4444 0     0     1     1
#> 19 394.7778 1     1     2     1
#> 20 391.0000 0     0     1     1
#> 21 326.7778 0     0     2     2
#> 22 323.0000 0     0     1     2
#> 23 334.3333 0     0     2     2
#> 24 330.5556 1     1     1     2
#> 25 341.8889 0     0     2     2
#> 26 338.1111 1     1     1     2
#> 27 349.4444 0     0     2     2
#> 28 345.6667 2     2     1     2
#> 29 357.0000 0     0     2     2
#> 30 353.2222 0     0     1     2
#> 31 364.5556 2     2     2     2
#> 32 360.7778 1     1     1     2
#> 33 372.1111 2     2     2     2
#> 34 368.3333 2     2     1     2
#> 35 379.6667 2     2     2     2
#> 36 375.8889 1     1     1     2
#> 37 387.2222 0     0     2     2
#> 38 383.4444 0     0     1     2
#> 39 394.7778 5     5     2     2
#> 40 391.0000 5     5     1     2

#Here's an approximation what I'd like to get as output:

diamonds %>% 
  filter(color == "E" | color == "J") %>% 
  filter(cut == "Good" | cut == "Premium") %>% 
  filter(price < 400) %>% 
  mutate(price_bin = cut(price, breaks = 10)) %>% 
  count(cut, color, price_bin)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>    cut     color price_bin     n
#>    <ord>   <ord> <fct>     <int>
#>  1 Good    E     (326,333]     1
#>  2 Good    E     (353,360]     1
#>  3 Good    E     (360,367]     1
#>  4 Good    E     (367,374]     2
#>  5 Good    E     (374,380]     2
#>  6 Good    J     (333,340]     2
#>  7 Good    J     (346,353]     2
#>  8 Good    J     (360,367]     1
#>  9 Good    J     (367,374]     1
#> 10 Good    J     (374,380]     2
#> 11 Good    J     (387,394]     5
#> 12 Premium E     (326,333]     1
#> 13 Premium E     (340,346]     2
#> 14 Premium E     (367,374]     4
#> 15 Premium E     (380,387]     2
#> 16 Premium E     (387,394]     1
#> 17 Premium J     (360,367]     2
#> 18 Premium J     (367,374]     2
#> 19 Premium J     (374,380]     2
#> 20 Premium J     (387,394]     5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Are you looking for this `p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, fill = as.factor(vs))) + geom_histogram(); pb <- ggplot_build(p); pb$data` ?

Comment: @markus No, see the bottom half of my question.

Comment: @jzadra It's not clear to me what you're asking. It seems to me that `ggplot_build(your_ggplot)$data` contains exactly what you're after (including the `group` label). This will also keep track of all the other aesthetic mappings (`colour`, `fill`, `linetype` etc.). Can you elaborate on why/how this doesn't do do what you're after?

Comment: In order to be informative, the table using the `ggplot_build` data would need to be labeled based on the fill or color grouping variables.  So rather than group being 1 or 2, it needs to say.... and I see the confusion.  In this case 0 and 1 matches what vs is.  But if vs were a character, the ggplot_build table would still show 1 or 2.  I'll update my question to show this. But it's the same for if there were facets.  The `ggplot_build` data output just lists them numerically - they would need to be labelebeled based on the actual value in the data.

Comment: * almost matches rather. The value of vs is 0 or 1, the group is 1, 2.

Comment: @jzadra The numeric (rather integer) labels should correspond to the `factor` levels of any `factor` variable used in an aesthetic mapping. So it would be straightforward to map numbers back to `character` levels. Can you edit your post to include a more representative example? Then it'll be much easier to give you a worked example solution.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have added another example that i hope is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not entirely clear on what it is you're after.

Let's consider the following minimal sample data

```
set.seed(2018)
df <- data.frame(
    x = sample(10),
    y = sample(10),
    group = sample(c("a", "b"), 10, replace = T))
#    x  y group
#1   4  4     a
#2   5  6     b
#3   1  8     a
#4   2  5     a
#5   3  7     b
#6   7 10     b
#7   6  2     a
#8   8  9     b
#9   9  3     b
#10 10  1     a
```

In this example, `df$group` is a `factor` with two levels `"a"` and `"b"`.

We now plot `df` with an additional `colour` aesthetic mapping to `df$group`

```
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = group)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
gg
```

[image]

To get the post-plotting data we use `ggplot_build`

```
pb <- ggplot_build(gg)
```

Notice how `pb` is a `list` that contains two elements for our two geometric objects `geom_point` and `geom_line`.

To extract the data and map `group` back to our `df$group` labels we can do the following

```
pb$data[[1]] %>%
    mutate(group_label = levels(df$group)[group])
#    colour  x  y PANEL group shape size fill alpha stroke group_label
#1  #F8766D  4  4     1     1    19  1.5   NA    NA    0.5           a
#2  #00BFC4  5  6     1     2    19  1.5   NA    NA    0.5           b
#3  #F8766D  1  8     1     1    19  1.5   NA    NA    0.5           a
#4  #F8766D  2  5     1     1    19  1.5   NA    NA    0.5           a
#5  #00BFC4  3  7     1     2    19  1.5   NA    NA    0.5           b
#6  #00BFC4  7 10     1     2    19  1.5   NA    NA    0.5           b
#7  #F8766D  6  2     1     1    19  1.5   NA    NA    0.5           a
#8  #00BFC4  8  9     1     2    19  1.5   NA    NA    0.5           b
#9  #00BFC4  9  3     1     2    19  1.5   NA    NA    0.5           b
#10 #F8766D 10  1     1     1    19  1.5   NA    NA    0.5           a
```

Here I map entries in `group` back to the actual `df$group` labels.

Comment: The problem here is that the original data `df` may not be what is passed to ggplot following a series of piped mutates, summaries, etc.  I can't refer back to original data object.

Comment: @jzadra I don't see the issue; store the data in its final form prior to plotting (so post-summarisation/reshaping); then you can always map integer aesthetic labels from `ggplot_build(...)$data` back to `character` labels from your data.

Comment: The problem is that I have hundreds of plots someone created and now need to create a table version of the results being visualized.

Comment: @jzadra Nope, I'm sorry but I don't understand the issue; you can always recover the raw data from `ggplot_build(...)$plot$data` (note, this is different from the post-plotting data). It's then straightforward to map one to the other.

Comment: Yeah, I've got the raw data, but no way to reconnect the labels.  The mapping between group values and labels ought ot exist somewhere, hopefully someone can tell me where!

Comment: @jzadra They are just the `factor` levels! That's what I've told you before! It seems we're going around in circles here.

Comment: The issue is that I know how to create this table through hacking it back together. In cases where the data piped to ggplot() has been modified in the pipe chain, the factor levels may be different than the starting df.  The goal is to take a ggplot object (nothing else) and create a table that represents the data shown.